# Separating values on imploded checkbox

Tags: php, checkbox, contact-form

I have a form which performs fine delivering all the values correctly.

However, is it possible to have all the imploded checkbox values on separate lines of the incoming email?

At the moment I can just a | or // or whatever between the values but for easier readability would like the values on separate lines.

My code (yes I know it is old):

```
//FORM PROCESSOR
// Specify your email here
$mail_to = 'xxxx.co.nz'; 

// Assigning data from $_POST array to variables
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$purchase = $_POST['purchase'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// pulldown
$motor = $_POST['motor'];

//checkboxes
$options = implode(' | ', $_POST['checkboxes1']);


// Construct subject of the email
$subject = '700 Quote Form';

// Construct email body
$body_message = 'Name: ' . $name . "\r\n";
$body_message .= 'Email: ' . $email . "\r\n";
$body_message .= 'Phone: ' . $phone . "\r\n";
$body_message .= 'Address: ' . $address . "\r\n";
$body_message .= 'Boat Purchase Date: ' . $purchase . "\r\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: ' . $message . "\r\n";
$body_message .= 'Trailer Option: ' . $trailer . "\r\n";
$body_message .= 'Motor Option: ' . $motor . "\r\n";
$body_message .= 'Options: ' . $options . "\r\n";
$check_msg;

// Construct headers of the message
$headers = 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";

$mail_sent = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_sent == true){ 
header('location: http://www.seaboss.co.nz/index.php/thanks');
exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: What keeps you from using another seperator? Why not use `PHP_EOL` instead of the given seperator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suppose that the posted checkbox values array looks something like this - where each value (here: 2, 3, 7) comes from the *"value"* attribute of an input of type *"checkbox"* with the name "checkboxes1[]":

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  > 2
    [1] =>  > 3
    [2] =>  > 7
)
```

That said, it could be better to separate the array assignation from the formatting of the array for display. The last step would join the array elements with a *new line string* ("\r\n") - resulting in displaying each array value on a separate line.

```
// Assignation of the posted array.    
$options = $_POST['checkboxes1'];

// Formatting for display.
$body_message .= 'Options:\r\n' . implode('\r\n', $options) . '\r\n';
```

If you'd want to also prepend a symbol (like " > ", for example) to each array value, then you'd have to apply an intermediary prefixing step:

```
// Assignation of the posted array.    
$options = $_POST['checkboxes1'];

// Prefixing array values.
foreach ($options as &$value) {
    $value = ' > ' . $value;
}

// Formatting for display.
$body_message .= 'Options:\r\n' . implode('\r\n', $options) . '\r\n';
```

Regarding the prefixing step, note the use of the *reference sign* ("&"). Thus each array value is directly modified, being assigned by reference. More details at

- [*foeach* construct](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and
- [References Explained](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php)

The resulting email text would then look like this:

```
Options:
 > 2
 > 3
 > 7
```

And a recommendation for building emails using beautiful templates: the [postmark-templates](https://github.com/wildbit/postmark-templates) project.

Comment: For the users who will, maybe, decide to downvote my answer: Please let me know the motive of your downvote, so that I can change the answer correspondingly. I am open to all your suggestions, or critiques. Thanks.

Comment: It seems you are used to downvotes? An answer should include a description of what you do or do differently than OP. If it does not include that it's considered a code only answer and those do attract downvotes.

Comment: Indeed, I am used to see (some of :) my answers downvoted without a description of the reason. Which I don't find fair and helpful for the continuous improvement of this website at all. Thanks for your suggestion, @Andreas.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PHP_EOL` to go to next line. Using this PHP_EOL will help the problems related to using linux or windows platforms.
Eg:

`$body_message = 'Name: ' . $name . PHP_EOL;
$body_message .= 'Email: ' . $email . PHP_EOL;`